# SQL create multiple columns based on distinct value of one column

Tags: sql, hive, pivot-table, impala

I have a table looks like this

```
-------------------------------
| col1 | col2 | count | value |
-------------------------------
| id1  | val1 | 1     |   2   | 
| id1  | val2 | 3     |   4   |
| id2  | val1 | 5     |   6   | 
| id2  | val2 | 7     |   8   |

....
```

I want to the final outcome to look like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| col1 | val1_count| val1_value| val2_count | val2_value | ... 
---------------------------------------------------------------
| id1  | 1         |  2        |   3        |  4         | 
| id2  | 5         |  6        |   7        |  8         |
....
```

It is pretty much the pivot table in Excel or the melt/cast in Python/R but is there an elegant SQL solution to achieve it? Luckily, There are only two distinct value for col2 - val1, val2 but it will be bonus points if there is a solution to scale to many value other than two.

Update, I am using Hive and Impala (both available to me)

Comment: I removed the incompatible SQL tags.  Someone with your reputation should know to tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I updated the post, I was using Hive and Impala and the table is pretty big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be

```
select col1, 
       max(case when col2 = 'val1' then count else null end) as val1_count,
       max(case when col2 = 'val1' then value else null end) as val1_value,
       max(case when col2 = 'val2' then count else null end) as val2_count,
       max(case when col2 = 'val2' then value else null end) as val2_value
from your_table
group by col1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses `join`:

```
select t1.col1, t1.count as val1_count, t1.value as val1_value,
       t2.count as val2_count, t2.value as val2_value
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t2.col2 = 'val2'
where t1.col2 = 'val1';
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.